# No Query defined for that name, when using Entity Manager

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, spring-boot

I have the following entity:

```
package com.server.models;
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@NamedQueries({
    @NamedQuery(name=User.QUERY_FIND_USER,query="SELECT c FROM user c WHERE c.username = :username")
})
public class User {

    public static final String QUERY_FIND_USER = "LoginFindUser";
    //  ...
}
```

And then using the Entity Manager (em) i'm doing the following:

```
package com.server.controllers;
@Service
@Transactional
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/user")
public class LoginController {
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;
 // my code
    TypedQuery<User> queries = em.createNamedQuery(User.QUERY_FIND_USER,User.class).setParameter("username", username);
    List<User> users = queries.getResultList();
}
```

However I am getting the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No query defined for that name [LoginFindUser]
```

Here's my spring-boot Configuration. This should include the scanning of the entity.

```
package com.server.boot;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan({"com.server"})
@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Starter {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        SpringApplication.run(Starter.class,args);
        System.out.println("started application");
    }

    @Bean
    public LoginController loginController(){
        return new LoginController();
    }

    @Bean
    public HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory(EntityManagerFactory emf) {
         HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean factory = new HibernateJpaSessionFactoryBean();
         factory.setEntityManagerFactory(emf);
         return factory;
    }

}
```

Comment: Does it work when you put a simple String as name? If yes, it's probably some evaluation time difference

Comment: Then check if `User` entity is defined in your persistence unit.

Comment: I'm using  spring-boot so the persistence is autodefined. The Context Scan should be including it

Comment: added the configuration to the question

Comment: Can you successfully fire a manual JPQL query that is not named? I'm kind of expecting that to blow up mentioning that the entity is not mapped.

Comment: And BTW, if the entity was mapped, you would get an exception because the query is invalid. user != User.

Comment: Is `@Entity` from `javax.persistence` package?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Found it. Thanks to the guys in the comments

Add

```
@EntityScan("com.server.models")
```

to your configuration class

and I had an error in the query cause `user` needed to be `User`

Comment: what is the version of persistence has this annotation ?

Comment: or to  <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.servers.model" /> if you are using old dispatcher-servlet.xml

Answer (score 8):

Okay, this might be an issue with you persistence configuration. If your models definitions are all in a separate ejb, make sure to add them in the persistence.xml in the persistence-unit

Answer (score 1):

You can do by below configuration.

```
private static final String[] ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN = { "a.b.c.entity" };

@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean() {

    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactoryBean = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdaptor());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource());
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPersistenceProviderClass(HibernatePersistenceProvider.class);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setPackagesToScan(ENTITYMANAGER_PACKAGES_TO_SCAN);
    entityManagerFactoryBean.setJpaProperties(jpaHibernateProperties());

    return entityManagerFactoryBean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this code snippet shown below.

```
<property name="packagesToScan" value="com.servers.model" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Add

> `entitymanager.packagesToScan:com.server.models`

to your application.properties file.